# turn on bean annotation processing with Java

Tags: spring

What is Java equivalent of following Spring bean XML configuration statement?

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

I am seeking for API calls on context which switch annotation processing on.

Comment: When do you want to switch it on and off? This property is used during spring initialization. You may prepare separate XML config file with and without annotation-config.

Comment: http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/01/spring-framework-without-xml-at-all.html

Comment: I want to switch it on. Without need this line to be included in xml configuration files.

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/20/bootstraping-a-web-application-with-spring-3-1-and-java-based-configuration-part-1/